# If I know the corresponding encoded bytes to some characters, how can I determine matching charsets?

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, scripting, character-encoding

I have a few files where the filenames obviously use the wrong charset. As soon as I know which charset is being used, I can use `convmv` to convert it to UTF-8. From the rest of the filename, I can find out which character is supposed to be there instead of the ugly symbols.

But how can I find out which charset it is?

I know, for example, that charset in question encodes the character `Ä` as hex `8e`, `ö` is `94` and so on. I have more characters to narrow it down further.

(If I had said `Ä` is `c4` and `ö` is `f6`, then - among others - [CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) would be a match, for example.)

Comment: There do exist some tools that can detect encoding. Maybe you can copy all the bytes into a file, then use a txt editor like gedit to open it, maybe it Will detect the correct encoding

Comment: It's probably cp850 or 437, but that's not a "how".

Comment: Look at it. If gedit fail, you can write your own tool. Like using Python, iterate all the encoding in the world, stop when the encoding map Ä to 0x8e and ö to 0x94

Comment: Then it's not a popular encoding. You can't find the whole mapping. Because you only has tiny part of the mapping. Like you know America's map, but can't guess world map from that.

Comment: `while read x ; do [[ " 948e" = "$(echo -n 'Äö' | iconv -t "${x%%/*}" | od -An -x)" ]] && echo ${x%%/*} ; done < <(iconv --list) 2>/dev/null` gives a fairly long list, but you have other characters to narrow it down.

Comment: @MichaelHomer This is great, that's exactly what I was looking for. Why didn't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I don't want to bother you :) Just checking: do you want to put your comment into an answer instead? Because this really did work fantastically.